# Chartkick gem: display legend vertically on top

Tags: ruby, legend, chartkick

I am using the ChartKick Ruby gem, and am trying to display the legend at the top (which I manage) with the items vertically (which I don't manage).

The legend keeps being displayed horizontally which is a problem for mobile devices.

My code:

```
<script>
    var Chartkick = {"language": "pt"};
</script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
<%= bar_chart metric, library: {colors: colors, backgroundColor: "#ffffff", hAxis:{title:hAxisTitle, format: '##########'}, vAxis:{title:vAxisTitle}, isStacked: true, legend: {layout: "vertical", position: "top"}, }, height: '200px' %>
```

The layout:vertical option simply doesn't seem to work :-(

Answer (score 1):

Please use this option for legend vertically on top

```
<%= pie_chart @job_acceptance , library: {legend: {position: "top"}}%>
```

Comment: This only puts the legend at the top, it does not lay it out vertically... which the OP already said they had accomplished.